# Navigation Stack: Invalid argument passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot be empty

Tags: ros, navigation, rviz, navfn, stack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to get the navigation stack working. I am publishing odometry data, tf data and laser scan to Navigation stack. But I get "Invalid argument passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot be empty" error when I initialize Rviz

Navfn ROS topic gives error "For Frame []: Frame [] does not exist". "Transform: [Sender =Unknown Publisher]"I am not able to generate any path to goal for my robot. Any ideas?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS Indigo

---

**Edited** part: More details
Here is the link to the source code: https://github.com/pchatrath/navigation-stack-quadcopter.git
I run the run_all script to get all things running. These are the steps that are undertaken:
1.Run roscore

2. Run houkuyo_node (frame laser)
3. Run robot_tf_publisher which is a static transform publisher between base_link and laser
4. Run  odometry_publisher code. I have written a subscriber which takes data from /cmd_vel topic and publishes it as output of odometry
5. Run move_base which configures all the costmap params. The link above has details about all the apramers that I configured.
6. run rviz

Questions that I have are - can i use odom as the global frame. Have I configured the odometry_publisher subscriber correctly?
Thanks

I have edited the code as guided. Path is not generated yet. Link to [tf tree pic](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1NX9BbQJSx1YmJqdEd6R1hnUDQ/view?usp=sharing)
[rviz](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1NX9BbQJSx1TTVuQTNjU1VDMlk/view?usp=sharing)
[source frame id error](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1NX9BbQJSx1U0ZFYjhiUGVsakE/view?usp=sharing)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225056/navigation-stack:-invalid-argument-passed-to-cantransform-argument-source_frame-in-tf2-frame_ids-cannot-be-empty/) by [automate](https://answers.ros.org/users/25620/automate/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2016-01-26

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The issue I guess was I wasn't using a static map for global costmap I had to state: static_map:false and rolling window: true. Now the robot navigates to goal position.

---

Originally posted by [automate](https://answers.ros.org/users/25620/automate/) with karma: 97 on 2016-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0